# Struggling with database design/relations

Tags: database-design, create-table

I'm trying to make a database for a construction depot (there where are stored materials for construction). I need to know all the materials stored (products in), all the products sold and all the products that had left.
I'm thinking to do like this:

```
Products--> Deliver <--Depot (many to many) - here I see all the products in.

Depot--> Sell <--Products (many to many) - here I see what I have sold.

And what is left: To make a difference between "Deliver" and "Sell".
```

Is there something correct here? Have you another idea? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to handle an inventory tracking system is to approach it like a **double-entry accounting** system.  This would have you combine your `Deliver` and `Sell` tables into an inventory `Movement` table.  Each movement would consist of two records, one with a positive quantity and one with a negative quantity.

The advantage of treating your inventory system this way is that it is easy to use an aggregate query to get the inventory position (stock on hand) of any product at any depot at a point in time.

---

**EDIT:** Table Structures...

```
PRODUCT
-ID (PK)
-Description
-...

DEPOT
-ID (PK)
-Name
-Location
-...

MOVEMENT
-ID (PK)
-DateTime
-ProductID (FK)
-DepotID (FK)
-Quantity /* Positive=Increase, Negative=Decrease */
-OffsettingMovementID (FK) /* Points to the other half of the entry */
```

Comment: So, you say that i will have a table Products, Depot and Movement, and this will be a many to many Product -> Movement <- Depot, and in the Movement table i will have the foreign keys colums of both Product and Depot and two column named In and Out. In - positive, Out - negative. Like this?

Comment: @MorarMihai - I've edited my answer to include sample columns.  The idea is not to have two columns: _in_ and _out_.  The idea is that every transaction has two records, one shows the movement out (quantity < 0) and the other shows the movement in (quantity > 0).  These two halves of the transaction can be linked with an involuted FK or with a common transaction ID number, whichever you prefer.  Getting the in-stock position for any product at any depot at any time becomes a straight forward SUM query.

Comment: Thank you Joel, you realy helped me.